# Migrating existing Realm objects with duplicate values to updated model with primary key?

Tags: swift, migration, realm

We have a Realm object model that looks like this:

```
class RealmGroup: Object {    
    @Persisted var name: String?
    @Persisted var groupId: Int? // this *should* have been the primary key
    @Persisted var groupPath: String?
}
```

We also have multiple object models that define a "group" property of type RealmGroup.  For example:

```
class A: Object {
    // other properties removed for brevity
    @Persisted var group: RealmGroup?
}

class B: Object {
    @Persisted var group: RealmGroup?
}

class C: Object {
    @Persisted var group: RealmGroup?
}
```

On one of my development phones, there are approximately 1000 A, B and C objects in the realm.  And across all 1000 of those objects, there may only be 10 - 15 *unique* group IDs.  The "groupId" property on the RealmGroup object *should* have been declared as the primary key so we'd only ever have one instance of RealmGroup with "groupId" = 12345, for example. And then, of course,  every A, B and C object belonging to that group would reference the same RealmGroup object.  But unfortunately, that wasn't caught until after we put this code into production.  So now I'm looking into the possibility of "fixing" this retroactively through a migration.

It seems understandable that I can't simply make the "groupId" property the primary key on the existing RealmGroup model since we already have multiple instances of RealmGroup objects with the same "groupId" value in the realm.  But beyond that, I'm not sure how I'd be able to implement this inside of a migration block.  The [Realm Swift SDK docs](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/realm/sdk/swift/model-data/change-an-object-model/) cover a few examples of migration but not exactly something like what I'm trying to accomplish.

Is it possible to do this without needing to create a new model (e.g., RealmGroupV2)?

Comment: Q: Is this a Sync'd app (or will be Sync'd in the future?). The question is a little unclear so more info is needed. Primary Keys are unique identifiers PER OBJECT. Per the question, I think you're stating there's 1000 RealmGroup objects but many of them share the same groupId i.e. there are 200 RealmGroup where the property `groupId` == 12345. Correct? So then, as-is, the A, B and C objects point to those 1000 RealmGroup objects (a primary key is not important in that case). So going forward, what are you going to do with the primary key? Is this so you can move to Sync or some other reason?

Comment: No, the realm is not synced and I don't believe there are plans to make it synced in the future, either.  And yes, your interpretation is correct.  Each instance of A, B or C objects are, unfortunately, creating their own instance of the RealmGroup object for the .group property.  The idea to make the groupId the primary key for RealmGroup would simply be to enforce that there can only ever be one instance of RealmGroup with groupId = 12345 and all objects belonging to that group would have their .group properties referencing the one instance of RealmGroup with a groupId = 12345.

Comment: But I'm having some trouble wrapping my head around doing this in a migration block.  As you cited above, if there are 200 existing RealmGroup objects with a groupId == 200, I'd like to create one instance of RealmGroup with groupdId = 200 (and make it the primary key), then update the .group property on all 200 of the A, B and C objects to point to it.

Comment: *creating their own instance of the RealmGroup*? I think you're using the word *instance* when you don't mean *instance* as that's not how Realm works. That property is a *reference* to the stored Realm object, not another *instance* of it. e.g. given 10 Person objects, P0, P1, P2... and they all had a `@Persisted var myDog: Dog` property where myDog = Spot, then they all have a *reference* to Spot, not 10 instances of Spot?? Let me restate the objective: given A, B, C objects that are pointing to *different* RealmGroups (id = 200), you want them to point at a single RealmGroup with id = 200.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion.  I was just referring to the fact that the initializers for A, B and C objects are creating a new instance of RealmGroup and then assigning it to their .group property.  We're definitely in agreement on my objective.   I think I need to create a new RealmGroupV2 object with groupId as the primary key for each unique group, iterate A/B/C objects to update the type of their group property to RealmGroupV2 and then assign the correct RealmGroupV2 object and lastly, remove all the RealmGroup objects from the realm.  Not sure this is all possible in a migration, though.

Comment: Yes, you can do all of that within a migration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if there's a better way to do this but I did finally get it working.  First, I created a new RealmGroupV2 model with the group ID defined as the primary key.  Then I added a new .group_v2 property to my A, B and C objects.  Finally, I performed the migration like this:

```
// enumerate all of the existing RealmGroup objects and create one new RealmGroupV2
// object for each unique group ID
var groupIds: [Int] = [] // keep track of the group IDs we've processed
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmGroup.className(), { oldGroupObject, _ in
    guard let oldGroupObject = oldGroupObject else { return }
    guard let groupId = oldGroupObject.value(forKey: "groupId") as? Int else { return }
    guard let name = oldGroupObject.value(forKey: "name") as? String else { return }
    guard let groupPath = oldGroupObject.value(forKey: "groupPath") as? String else { return }

    if groupIds.contains(groupId) == false {
        // create a new RealmGroupV2 object for this group
        let groupV2 = migration.create(RealmGroupV2.className())
        groupV2["groupId"] = groupId
        groupV2["name"] = name
        groupV2["groupPath"] = groupPath
        // add groupId to the groupIds array so we don't try to create another
        // RealmGroupV2 for this groupId
        groupIds.append(groupId)
    }
})

// enumerate all of the existing A objects, assign a RealmGroupV2 object to the
// new .group_v2 property and set the now-deprecated .group property to nil
migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: A.className(), { oldObject, newObject in
    guard let oldObject = oldObject else { return }
    guard let newObject = newObject else { return }
    guard let groupObject = oldObject["group"] as? Object else { return }
    guard let groupId = groupObject.value(forKey: "groupId") as? Int else { return }

    migration.enumerateObjects(ofType: RealmGroupV2.className(), { oldGroupV2Object, newGroupV2Object in
        guard let newGroupV2Object = newGroupV2Object else { return }

        if let groupIdFromV2Object = newGroupV2Object["groupId"] as? Int {
            if groupIdFromV2Object == groupId {
                newObject["group_v2"] = newGroupV2Object
                newObject["group"] = nil
            }
        }
    })
})

// *** repeat above migration for B and C objects ***

// finally, delete all of the old RealmGroup objects
migration.deleteData(forType: RealmGroup.className())
```

I'm sure there are ways to improve upon this but hopefully it will help someone else who might be struggling with a similar situation.